# $\min_{x\in [0,1]} \left(\frac{x^2+x\sqrt2 +1}{x+1}+\frac{1-x}{\sqrt2}\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

> Determine
> $$\min_{x\in [0,1]} \left(\frac{x^2+x\sqrt2 +1}{x+1}+\frac{1-x}{\sqrt2}\right)$$

Wolfram say that this minimum is $4(\sqrt{2}-1)$ (when $x=\sqrt{2}-1$), and the function is convex, but I cannot prove this.

Comment: Hint: $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x^2+x\sqrt2 +1}{x+1}+\frac{1-x}{\sqrt2}\right)=\frac{(x+1)(2x+\sqrt{2})-(x^2+x\sqrt{2}+1)}{(x+1)^2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
Put $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ and find critical points form the quadratic equation

Comment: The objective function is written as $\frac{2-\sqrt 2}{2}\left((x + 1) + \frac{2}{x+1}\right) + 2\sqrt 2 - 2$.

Comment: @RiverLi How did you get this?

Comment: @user986772 Just do this $\frac{x^2+x\sqrt2 +1}{x+1} = x - 1 + \sqrt2 + \frac{2-\sqrt2}{x + 1}$.

Comment: @RiverLi Thanks!

Comment: @user986772 You are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After calculation, we see that:

$$f'(x) = \frac{(\sqrt2 - 1)x^2 + (2\sqrt 2 - 2)x + 1-\sqrt2}{\sqrt2 (x+1)^2}$$

So the sign of $f'(x)$ is the same as the sign of the numerator. The numerator has the roots $-1 \pm \sqrt2$, from which we deduce the variations: $f$ is decreasing over $[0,-1+\sqrt2]$ and increasing over $[-1+\sqrt2, 1]$, so it attains its minimum at $x = -1+\sqrt 2$, and the minimum is $f(-1+\sqrt2) = 4(\sqrt2 -1)$.